# How to make a destructor for class into another class with pointers C++? Something like one-direction list container class and class of nodes

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor

```
class lista {
class wezel {
    wezel *nast; // next node in list
    std::string napis; // string in node
                  // ...
public:
    void set_napis(string napis1) { napis = napis1; }
    void set_nast(wezel *nast1) { nast = nast1; }
    wezel(const std::string napis1, wezel *nast1) : napis(napis1), nast(nast1) {}
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &wy, const wezel &wzl) {
        if (wzl.nast) return wy << wzl.napis << ", " << *wzl.nast;
        else return wy << wzl.napis;
    }

};
wezel *poczatek; // pointer to the beg of the list
public:
lista();
lista(const lista &lst);
lista(lista &&lst);
lista(initializer_list<std::string> lst);
lista& operator= (const lista &lst);
lista& operator= (lista &&lst);
~lista();

public:
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &wy, const lista &lst) {
    if (lst.poczatek) return wy << "(" << *lst.poczatek << ")";
    else return wy << "()";
}
```

};

I want to write destructor that deletes not only member of class lista but also wezel (all nodes) The pointer in wezel means that pointer to the next element of list is *nast. If it's nullpointer it's the end of the list. I know i shouldn't make any destructors for string but what about those pointers etc. ?

Big apologies for my english. I am from Poland ;) Greets ;)

Comment: Why not just use http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/ instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: because it is our task from tutor :)

Comment: I see - you want us to write your homework.

Comment: Well, as a general rule, classes are supposed to take care of themselves. So the other class needs to have its own destructor. All that's left to do in the main class, then, is to delete the other class, so that destructor gets invoked.

Comment: @Ed Heal It is only small part of my "homework"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you have no control on how the `wezel` were created. If they have been created with `new`, fine, just `delete` them. But if a bunch have been created with `new[]`, then they should be destroyed with a `delete[]`, and if one was just created *on stack* in the main (`wezel wezel1("mystring");`) it should not be deleted at all: it will disappear automatically at the end of the function or block where it has been declared.

TL/DR: unless the API explicitely states that all `wezel` in a `lista` **must** have been created with `new`, you should not try to delete them.

Or: you should use a method in `lista` to add a new string and create the `wezel` in that method with `new`. That way you control how it has been created and can safely `delete` it.